# How to split in javascript in multiple places

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file which requires splitting into arrays so i can populate a select2 dropdown.

Here's the format of the json:

```
[{
  "entry_id": "MY_ID",
  "title": "MY TITLE",
  "url": "MY URL",
  "count": "MY COUNT"
},

{
  "entry_id": "MY_ID 2",
  "title": "MY TITLE 2",
  "url": "MY URL 2",
  "count": "MY COUNT 2"
}]
```

I've been using these lines of javascript (part of a larger script):

```
data[i] = data[i].split(",\"title\": ");
data[i][0] = data[i][0].slice(13, -1);
data[i][1] = data[i][1].slice(1, -1);
```

in order to extract the "MY ID" and "MY TITLE" values for use in the dropdown, but have realised this is splitting into two arrays and I am not getting the title text properly which is causing an error.

I think I need to split in three places: the "title":, "url": and "count": and not just the "title":

I don't suppose there's any way of making that split function work on multiple patterns?

Comment: Why aren't you `JSON.parse()`ing the JSON and accessing the object properties like normal: `data.title` etc?

Comment: Your format isn't JSON. Either add characters to convert it so you can parse it, or write a simple parser, which should be pretty easy for that data.

Comment: `console.log({"entry_id": "MY_ID",
"title": "MY TITLE",
"url": "MY URL",
"count": "MY COUNT"}.title)`

Comment: The curly quotes etc are most certainly on the json file which i am accessing. It's just not on the code I've pasted in above. Apologies for the confusion with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
obj.entry_id;
```

Should be enough.

Comment: Your code is not valid JS and OPs "object" is not a JS object or JSON anything unless it is wrapped in {} `obj.entry_id;` does not do anything on its own

Comment: It actually is a JSON object, OP just forgot to paste the whole JSON file as stated in  his own comment

Comment: Yep sorry, I've edited my post to fully reflect the json file structure.

Answer (score 0):

*Update*

Since you clarified that you do have valid JSON, then it's just a matter of using my first example below without adding in the braces.

And if you only want the `entry_id` and `title`, you can use destructuring assignment.

```js
var d = `{
  "entry_id": "MY_ID",
  "title": "MY TITLE",
  "url": "MY URL",
  "count": "MY COUNT"
}`;

const {entry_id, title} = JSON.parse(d);
console.log(entry_id, title);
```

---

Your data as shown is a custom format, not JSON. Given that specific data, you can convert it to valid JSON by adding curly braces. This will let you parse and read the data.

```js
var d = `"entry_id": "MY_ID",
"title": "MY TITLE",
"url": "MY URL",
"count": "MY COUNT"`;

var json = "{" + d + "}";

var parsed = JSON.parse(json);

for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(parsed)) {
  console.log(key, val);
}
```

Or given that data format as shown, a simple parser should be pretty easy to write. This should give you a good start.

```js
var d = `"entry_id": "MY_ID",
"title": "MY TITLE",
"url": "MY URL",
"count": "MY COUNT"`;

var parsed = parse(d);

for (const [key, val] of parsed) {
  console.log(key, val);
}

function parse(d) {
  var res = [];
  var key, val;

  while (d.length) {
    [key, d] = parseString(d.trim());
    d = d.trim();
    if (d[0] !== ":") {
      throw "Invalid data";
    }

    [val, d] = parseString(d.slice(1).trim());
    res.push([key, val]);
    d = d.trim();
    if (d[0] !== ",") {
      break;
    }

    d = d.slice(1)
  }
  if (d.length) {
    throw "Invalid data";
  }
  return res
}

function parseString(d) {
  var i = 0;
  if (d[i++] !== '"') {
    throw "Invalid string; expected open quote";
  }
  while (i < d.length && d[i] !== '"') {
    i++;
  }
  if (d[i++] !== '"') {
    throw "Invalid string; expected close quote";
  }
  return [d.slice(1, i - 1), d.slice(i)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add curly braces to your JSON data to create a valid JSON string.
Pass your JSON string to JSON.parse() to create an object.
Access the object properties by name.

```
jsonString = '{"entry_id": "MY_ID", "title": "MY TITLE", "url": "MY URL", "count": "MY COUNT" }';

myObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

entryId = myObject.entry_id;
title = myObject.title;

console.log(entryId);
console.log(title);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g9ko8tk9/